# AddPicture shows correct top value but displays images shifted down to another position in different screen sizes or resolutions

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA I used AddPicture function to add, position and resize images on a worksheet. To do this I used a dynamic positioning formula to avoid problems when zoomed in or changed to a smaller screen. Everything worked great until another colleague tried to use the same Excel in their laptops or PC's but the images were shifting more and more downwards when the row number increased. The horizontal alignment was working well (which was the harder one to do) but oddly the vertical alignment on the screen was moved downwards even the calculation and "Top" value was correct. I am trying to solve this like for 2 days but I still couldn't find a reason or solution for this problem. Thank you for your comments or answers.

The code I use:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
    Filename:=FolderPath & ProductName & ".JPG", _
    linktofile:=msoFalse, _
    savewithdocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=((ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns.Width) / 4), _
    Top:=((ActiveCell.Row + 1) * ActiveCell.RowHeight), _
    Width:=(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Height - (4 * ActiveCell.RowHeight)), _
    Height:=(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Height - (4 * ActiveCell.RowHeight))
```

Note: Another function aligns the screen to the 1 upper cell/row
Note 2: I add product images which are originally 1024 x 1024 in size
The left position should be in the middle of the screen (but also when zoomed in or using  a smaller display)
The top position of the added picture should be 1 row below of the selected cell/row
The size should also be dynamic and square. To make the images always fit to the screen I used the "VisibleRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Height" function to get the total height of the visible rows and subtracted 4 row heights from it.

Comment: Possibly a screen shot of what is happening. I am assuming the height would be affected by hidden rows.

Comment: Just a thought: But have tried adding the picture as is, and (post adding) do the positon and sizing stuff. Would eliminate any undocumented features of `AddPicture`. To add a picture 'as is': 1) `.Select` the Target Cell and 2) use `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert...`.